# “Cannabis” vs. “marijuana” vs. “weed”

Tags: meaning, slang, spanish

I know all these words have the same meaning and refer to some kind of plant.

Also, as far as I know, *weed* is the slang for *marijuana* or *cannabis*. (Correct me if I’m wrong).

What I do not understand is the difference between these words. Is *cannabis* a formal word, and *marijuana* and *weed* both informal?

Does one or two of these words originated from South America — for example, has a Spanish root — and the others originated from elsewhere?

Comment: As a tiny note, the Anglicization of "marijuana" leads to one of the street names for it: "Mary Jane".

Comment: The word *marijuana* seems to be used more commonly by Americans. *Cannabis* and the slang names for it, are more common in the UK.

Comment: Marijuana is not a herb, it's a plant. Herbs are thyme, marjoram, rosemary, basil, sage etc. aromatic plants used to flavour dishes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ***OED**: herb, n. 1. A plant of which the stem does not become woody and persistent (as in a shrub or a tree), but remains more or less soft and succulent, and dies down to the ground (or entirely) after flowering.*

Comment: @Greybeard I shall visit my local supermarket and ask for a bottle of dried marijuana to sprinkle on top of my spaghetti ai pomodorini. Of course herbs are plants, so is a tree and a rose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the context. If you are referring to it scientifically, you call it *cannabis* (usually *cannabis indica* or *cannabis sativa*). Marijuana is a generic term mostly used by non-users. People who smoke the drug have a seemingly inexhaustible supply of slang terms for their favorite recreational drug, of which *weed* and *bud* are currently in vogue. You would not be likely to use those terms unless you don't mind people assuming you use the drug yourself, because they very likely will make that assumption.

EDIT: You can use the term *pot* in a disinterested way, as someone pointed out. *Weed* flirts with crossing the line, however, and *bud* is tantamount to a term of endearment.

Comment: More normally 'depends' than 'depemds' :D

Comment: >>You would not be likely to use those terms unless you don't mind people assuming you use the drug yourself>> Just to be sure, So if I mention that as "pot" then it means I use drug? But If I use Marijuana, it does not mean that.

Comment: Weed has significant uses completely unrelated to marijuana or cannabis - think horticulture or gardening.  Without context, it could easily be misunderstood.

Comment: I disagree that "pot" implies usage. ("Weed" probably does.) "Pot" is, for me, the unmarked term, with "marijuana" and "cannabis" reserved for a more formal or scientific register.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: True, but it's rarely ambiguous: "weed" is used uncountably for marijuana, and countably for other sorts of weeds. Consider "I picked weeds from my garden today" versus "I picked weed from my garden today". The latter definitely refers to marijuana. And if you say "I smoked weed today", there is no question about what kind.

Comment: @JSBangs: I made no reference to the word *pot*. @Jonathan: I am assuming a drug context; of course *weed*has the more "garden-variety" meaning. The two are unlikely to be confused except out of context. Thanks for noting the typo, though. My smart phone isn't smart enough, apparently.

Comment: I'd just use the word "hemp"... :D

Comment: That must be why a guy’s best friend is his bud, and why  “Please Keep Off the Grass” signs are his worst enemy.

Comment: As far as I understand the difference as a Cannabis gardener, Cannabis is the name of the plant family, while Marijuana mainly refers to a specific product from the plant: The dried flowers and sometimes leaves intended for consumption generally by smoking them. Other products have different names; i.e. the extracted resin glands are usually referred to as hash. Weed, dope, Mary Jane, etc. are all slang terms. Though this being terminology used widely all over the world in a drug related setting, I'm sure exact definitions vary, or rather do not exist. :)

Comment: In my opiion, a more direct answer, no less intelligent, must be NO. Simply. There is no difference in the diction of these terms. It does not matter the context either of these terms are used in most everyone will instantly know and understand what is meant. - Anonymous comment inserted as edit.